# Mangum adapter unable to infer handler to use for event on AWS API Gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, fastapi, mangum

I have deployed an API to AWS Lambda, code written with FastAPI framework and Mangum. The URL given by AWS Lambda worked well. However, when I deploy the Lambda on API Gateway, it showed the following error

```
{
  "errorMessage": "The adapter was unable to infer a handler to use for the event. This is likely related to how the Lambda function was invoked. (Are you testing locally? Make sure the request payload is valid for a supported handler.)",
  "errorType": "RuntimeError",
  "requestId": "<removed-by-me>",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/mangum/adapter.py\", line 76, in __call__\n    handler = self.infer(event, context)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/mangum/adapter.py\", line 68, in infer\n    raise RuntimeError(  # pragma: no cover\n"
  ]
}
```

Which is totally weird, because the API url is worked on Lambda, but can't worked on API Gateway! Extra information, I used proxy as resource.

Anyone please help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems everything is perfect but aws lambda uses mangum as handler and this handler doesn't understand the default event structure. So you just have to create a **new event** with a template **apigateway-aws-proxy**. Now change a few things under PATH : "/" and HTTPMETHOD : "GET" everywhere. It will give you want you want.Pls look at the image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6bhf.png

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when we don't enable below flag in the create method page under any Resource in API gateway.

**Enable this flag**

**Lambda proxy integration**
Send the request to your Lambda function as a structured event.
Please click on the below image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3eb1.png)